Principled BSDF Normal Input Default Value problem
The Principled BSDF node has the socket inputs named Normal, with python I checked the values ​​are set to (0, 0, 0)
To check I did:
>>> bsdf = C.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF']
>>> print(bsdf.inputs['Normal'].default_value[:])
>>> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

If I connect a "Reroute" socket nothing happens.
However, if I connect a group node with values ​​of 0,0,0 the normal seems to mess everything up.
Does anyone have any idea why and how to fix it with right default_value?
This is the Example:

Note
This problem only happens with Eevee and not in Cycles.

Off the top of my head, the default normal should be 0,0,1.

I think there is something wrong with Eevee, as this in Cycles leaving the values ​​at 0,0,0 seems to not create problems.

I came across this tip in the Blender Docs today:

If the Height input is not connected, the (Bump) node becomes a no-op that outputs its Normal input as is, or defaults to the geometry normal if not connected. Routing a node group input via a no-op Bump node before doing math effectively makes it default to normal.

